# SQL Error [58030]: ERROR: Query aborted due to read failure on a perm block

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We have created datashare (environments) in redshift where we are binding 1 table from `environment A` named `tableA` to `environment B` named `tableB` .

We access both tables from `environment A`. We were able to access these both tables for few weeks but from yesterday we are getting following error which does not have any info available on web.

`SQL Error [58030]: ERROR: Query aborted due to read failure on a perm block. Hint: Please try again.`

We can access `tableB` from `environmentB (datashare)` but only getting this when we try to access `tableB` from `environment A (datashare A)`. Dropping bidning and recreating these tables  and again linking these 2 tables solves the issue for some time where we can access the tables from both `datashares`. But error again comes back after some time. Does anyone know why this issue is arising?`

We recreated the tables and binding between these 2 tables in redshift, it worked for some time, but issue repeats

Comment: Have you submitted a support ticket with AWS?  This sounds like an issue accessing the table through 2 different envs where caching may be causing issues.  It could be a corner case they haven't thought through yet.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem recently. In our case, restoring the datashare did not solve the problem. Instead, recreating the referenced table solved the problem.